# Camera Sensitivity Multiplication not working in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, math, 3d, game-development

The multiplication of the camera sensitivity times the Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") dosen't change the value, for my first person controller.Multiplication with Time.deltaTime works perfectly though.

I tried messing around with the syntax, yet it didnt work. I had expected for the camera sensitivity to change. This is the code -->

```
tyusing System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class MovementScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject Camera;
    public float cs = 1000f;

    private float yRot = 0f;

    void Start()
    {
        Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.identity;
        transform.localRotation = Quaternion.identity;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        updatePlrRotation();
    }

    void updatePlrRotation()
    {
        float msX = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * Time.deltaTime;
        float msY = Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * Time.deltaTime;

        Vector3 xRot = new Vector3(0, cs*msX, 0);
        yRot -= msY * cs;

        Debug.Log(xRot);

        Mathf.Clamp(yRot, -90, 90);

        transform.Rotate(xRot);
        transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(yRot, transform.localRotation.eulerAngles.y, 0);
    }

}
```

Comment: You forgot to assign the value back to your variable.  `yRot = Mathf.Clamp(yRot, -90, 90)`

Comment: Am I supposed to reassign after clamping?

Comment: Clamp returns the clamped value.  If you want the yRot to be clamped, you need to assign the return value back to your variable.

Comment: The clamp worked either ways, and adding it to return value didnt change anything.

Comment: I can guarantee that clamp does not work unless you assign the value back.  When debugging a vector, it is important to know that unity will round the component values to a single decimal place.  The value of cs*msX might be so small that it appears to not change.  Try debugging the individual values to get all the decimal places.  `Debug.Log($"({xRot.x}, {xRot.y}, {xRot.z})");`

Comment: I did increase the value of cs to millions and billions. The values still don't change.